# What kind of different ways are there for an Java web application to store the JDBC connection string and parameters?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, tomcat6

What kind of different ways are there for an Java web application to store the JDBC connection string and parameters?

The two ways of doing this that I am aware of is:
1. application side
2. environment side (JNDI)

Could someone elaborate on these? Like on the application side using a properties file. But is it possible to use an external properties file that multiple applications would have access to?

FYI: My environment includes Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The two ways of doing this that I am aware of is: 1. application side 2. environment side (JNDI) Could someone elaborate on these? Like on the application side using a properties file.*

The environment side has the advantage that it offers a single ready-to-use connection **pool** for all webapps, so that you don't need to configure/program it from every individual webapplication on. The application side has the advantage that you have 100% control over it from the webapplication on. This advantage is however discutable; there's potential code duplication and the maintenance is clumsy.

---

> *But is it possible to use an external properties file that multiple applications would have access to?*

Yes, just put it in a shared classpath location (in Tomcat, you can set it by `shared.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties`). You only need to control the connection (pool) creation in every webapplication yourself. Using a JNDI connection pooled datasource is more recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Yyou can use a connection pool from the application side (if you use Spring framework it is really easy to configure a Commons-DBCP pool).

I recommend to define the DataSource in Tomcat's server.xml file, and in your webapp add a META-INF/context.xml file with a Resource Link pointing to the JNDI location of the Tomcat's DataSource. This way you can share the same connection pooling with other webapps deployed in Tomcat.